# 'Text to column' delimit function but for multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have 10 cells with data in a row, and I have to delimit them one by one by using the 'text to column' function in excel and placing the output in a separate column/area. Is it possible to delimit multiple cells and place the outputs in order? Below is an example of what I am aiming for:

[image: Raw data input]

My goal is to delimit the Col_A to Col_D cell values and place the outputs in the Part1 and Part 2 columns to the right in order like so:

[image: After Delimiting by ';']

The method I am using now is to use the 'Text to columns' function to manually delimit each of the Col_A to Col_D 1 by 1 into their respective output columns.

Is there a way for me to delimit the Col_A to Col_D values all at once by order?

PS: I'm not very good at VBA, so if the solution requires VBA/Macros kindly leave some documentation for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(";",,A1:D1),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

---

For previous version of Excel there would be multiple routes; one could be:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1&";"&$B1&";"&$C1&";"&$D1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")
```

Drag right. Or, a bit more dynamic:

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE({1;2},MID($A1:$D1,FIND(";",$A1:$D1)+1,LEN($A1:$D1)),LEFT($A1:$D1,FIND(";",$A1:$D1)-1)),MOD(COLUMN(),2)+1,CEILING(COLUMN(A1)/2,1))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag right.

Comment: One more question, do you know if this formula will work in Excel 2016? Haha

Comment: It won't, it's a spilled array available from ms365 @BryanArtic.

Comment: Do you know of any alternative formulas I can use for Excel 2016? @JvdV

Comment: @BryanArtic, see update.

Comment: I tried both the formulas, they both returned #VALUE errors

Comment: Cancel last please,
Update: I pasted it again on the right side (after the data), it returned '123' and when I drag it to the right, it returned the #REF error followed by the next number which is 456

Comment: @BryanArtic, strange. I tested it in Excel2016 on my workstation and they worked fine. If your data is not from `A1:D1` there are some obvious tweak you need to make.

Comment: Did you use the alternative formulas starting with FILTERXML or INDEX? I will try it out when I get back to my workstation. I will update again whether it works or not. Thank you!

Comment: @BryanArtic, both worked for me. Maybe change the comma in `{1,2}` into a semi-colon > `{1;2}` and try again (Don't forget to CSE). The 1st option does not need array-entering.

Answer (score 1):

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(";",,1:1),";","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"))` is the best option without VBA (like JvdV already posted)

For non-Windows you could use this in a cell in the first column:
`=IFERROR(IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN()),RIGHT(INDEX(1:1,,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)),LEN(INDEX(1:1,,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)))-FIND(";",INDEX(1:1,,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)))),LEFT(INDEX(1:1,,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)),FIND(";",INDEX(1:1,,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0)))-1)),"")`

Comment: Hello, may I know if this formula can be used in Excel 2016? @P.b

Comment: The lower formula is usable in previous Excel versions. It only works if there's one delimiter per cell (as the example) and needs manual dragging the formula to the right.

Comment: I'll try it out when I get back to my workstation, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, another which will work for all Excel versions:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($A1:$D1,INT((1+COLUMNS($A1:A1))/2)),";",REPT(" ",99)),99*ISEVEN(COLUMNS($A1:A1))+1,99))`

and copied right.

Or, for O365, if returning the results to a rectangular range is acceptable:

`=LEFT(MID(A1:D1,FIND(";",A1:D1)^{0;1}+{0;1},99),FIND(";",A1:D1)^{1;9}-1)`

Comment: It returns the values before the ";" and not the ones after though

Comment: @Bryan Artic To which of the two formulas are you referring?

Comment: The first one returns ABC (Blank) DEF (Blank) and the second one returns the output mentioned above

Comment: Based on the sample data you provided, both return the correct desired results. The first one is designed for non-365 and needs to be dragged right. For the second, perhaps you are having issues since, for your version of Excel, the separator for vertical arrays is not the semicolon, so the parts `{0;1}`, `{0;1}`ì and `{1;9}` would need to be amended. You can easily confirm what the vertical separator is for your version of Excel by entering the formula `=A1:A3` somewhere, then going into the formula bar and highlighting it and pressing F9.